# How can I make Numba access arrays as fast as Numpy can?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

## Problem

Numpy is basically faster at copying array content to another array (or so it seems, for large-enough arrays).

I'm **not** expecting Numba to be faster but **nearly as fast** seems like a reasonable target.

## Minimum working example

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def copyto_numpy(a, b):
    np.copyto(a, b, 'no')

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def copyto_numba(a, b):
    N = len(a)
    for i in range(N):
        b[i] = a[i]

a = np.random.rand(2**20)
b = np.empty_like(a)
copyto_numpy(a, b)
copyto_numba(a, b)

%timeit copyto_numpy(a, b)
%timeit copyto_numba(a, b)
```

## Timings

```
1.28 ms ± 5.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
2.19 ms ± 222 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

## Other things tried (and failed)

- Dummy loop in the functions to "stay longer in no-python mode";
- Capture `N` from the environment (i.e. no `N = len(a)`);
- Force use of flattened arrays: `b.flat[i] = a.flat[i]`;
- Use `fastmath=True` and/or `nogil=True` in case it triggers vectorization;
- Change the type of the loop counter to unsigned integer (32 bits and 64 bits);
- Remove the loop and copy the full array at once: `b[:] = a` (twice slower!);
- New version with Cython (as fast as Numba, slower than Numpy, slight variation from @MSeifert's answer):

  ```
  %load_ext cython

  %%cython -c=-march=native -c=-O3 -c=-ftree-vectorize -c=-flto -c=-fuse-linker-plugin
  cimport cython

  @cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking
  @cython.wraparound(False)   # Deactivate negative indexing.
  cpdef copyto_cython_flags(double[::1] in_array, double[::1] out_array):
      cdef Py_ssize_t idx, N = len(in_array)
      for idx in range(N):
          out_array[idx] = in_array[idx]
  ```
- Checked CPU usage to confirm Numpy was only using one core.

Again, I'm not expecting Numba to be faster but certainly not 70% slower! Is there anything I can do to make this faster? Note that `np.copyto` is not implemented in nopython mode so it gets very slow with small vectors.

---

[image: Timing comparison of Numba, Cython and Numpy copy_to functions vs. array size.]

Comment: The numpy function is using a highly-optimized piece of C-code under the hood (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e8689171bb5830e7c607d4c398353dc8707c0106/numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign_array.c#L68-L146), so it's possible that the generated LLVM is missing some optimization.

Comment: Which Numba version, Python version, working system, you are on? Both timings looks quite slow I got 673 µs (Numpy) 615 µs (Numba) on Windows 10, Python 3.7.1, Numba 0.45.0, Core i5,8xxx

Comment: Latest ArchLinux, Python 3.7.4, Numba 0.45.1 core i7,4xxxU i.e. latest software. Absolute speed don't matter: it's the relative one that does. If you get those numbers, it just means that you need to increase the array size even more: the asymptote is what is interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not expecting Numba to be faster but certainly not 70% slower!

In my experience that's pretty much always the case, except you're willing to sacrifice accuracy (`fastmath` - not relevant here because we're not doing any math) or you can utilize multi-threading (in this case probably not worth it because copy is basically memory-bandwidth limited) or multi-processing (as the other answer show this can make it faster for larger arrays). After all it's comparing hand-written (often highly-optimized) code with auto-generated code. That should also answer the question title:

> How can I make Numba access arrays as fast as Numpy can?

It's unlikely that you can with numba! Often it's 50-200% slower on big arrays if you try to re-implement some native-NumPy functionality with numba and that's already quite close.

Numba excels when you need to write code operating on arrays that is **not** already implemented in NumPy, SciPy, or any other optimized library.

---

However numba is already faster than similar code with Cython (which I find amazing):

[image]

```
%load_ext cython

%%cython
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking
@cython.wraparound(False)   # Deactivate negative indexing.
cpdef copyto_cython(double[::1] in_array, double[::1] out_array):
    cdef Py_ssize_t idx
    for idx in range(len(in_array)):
        out_array[idx] = in_array[idx]
```

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def copyto_numpy(a, b):
    np.copyto(a, b, 'no')

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def copyto_numba(a, b):
    N = len(a)
    for i in range(N):
        b[i] = a[i]
```

I'm using my own library [`simple_benchmark`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/simple_benchmark) for the performance measurements here:

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder, MultiArgument

b = BenchmarkBuilder()

b.add_functions([copyto_cython, copyto_numpy, copyto_numba])

@b.add_arguments('array size')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(4, 21):
        size = 2**exp
        arr = np.random.rand(size)
        arr2 = np.empty(size)
        yield size, MultiArgument([arr, arr2])

r = b.run()
r.plot()
```

Comment: To be fair to Cython, you would need to use a few additional compiler flags to get an apple to apple comparison (at least to let gcc use autovectorization).

Comment: @user11488411 At least when I tested it practically made no difference with compiler flags, also because that's highly compiler -dependent (I'm using MSVC) it's completely out-of-scope for a numba question. Did you manage to get noteworthy better performance with Cython using compiler flags?

Comment: Are you on a dual socket workstation (or at least with 4 or more memory channels)? On a machine like this numpy vs numba looks quite similar than your mesurements, but not on a desktop PC. (The bump on 2*10**5 isn't there). The cython solution also seems to work better with gcc on linux.

Comment: @max9111 Is the Cython version faster than numba/NumPy or just "less slower" with gcc?

Comment: @max9111 I don't think the "bump" is really interesting here - because I was mostly interested in the relative performance. These bumps are often the result of "hitting a lucky number" or "exceeding some threshold" - with too many moving parts to draw conclusions regarding performance comparisons. However if there are different trends on your desktop computer, i.e. NumPy being slower than numba on huge arrays, that would be very interesting.

Comment: @MSeifert I agree for Cython. My phrasing was wrong: I meant to say that, at least with GCC, on Linux, using ``%%cython -c=-march=native -c=-O3 -c=-ftree-vectorize`` (or even ``-Ofast``, when ``fastmath=True`` is used) is fairer when comparing to Numba (seen too many benchmarks like that in the past). The point was just: Cython is a fair bit slower and it's fine for this question but if you, reader from the future, try this at home, remember that there is more than ``gcc -O2``

Comment: @max9111 No, I'm on a laptop from a few years back. I know my memory bandwidth is not as great as a typical desktop's... But that's the point: it means that ``np.copyto`` is less wasteful of that bandwidth...

Comment: @MSeifert: actually, activating the flags above plus ``-c=-flto -c=-fuse-linker-plugin`` makes Cython exactly as fast as Numba.

Comment: Anyway, I got the message: if Cython is as slow, it means the bottleneck is elsewhere (probably in Numpy's C API that is partially bypassed in copyto).

Answer (score 1):

### There may be an impact of switching to a parallelized version

It looks like Numba is a tiny bit faster on small arrays, and on par on medium sized arrays. For larger arrays it looks like Numpy is switching to parallelized copy, which has to be implemented in Numba manually.
I don't know why cython performance is significantly slower, but this may be due to some compiler flags.

**Code**

```
%load_ext cython

%%%%cython -c=-march=native -c=-O3 -c=-ftree-vectorize -c=-flto -c=-fuse-linker-plugin
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking
@cython.wraparound(False)   # Deactivate negative indexing.
cpdef copyto(double[::1] in_array, double[::1] out_array):
    cdef Py_ssize_t idx
    for idx in range(len(in_array)):
        out_array[idx] = in_array[idx]

import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def copyto_numpy(a, b):
    np.copyto(a, b, 'no')

@nb.jit(nopython=True,parallel=True)
def copyto_numba_p(a, b):
    N = len(a)
    for i in nb.prange(N):
        b[i] = a[i]

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def copyto_numba_s(a, b):
    N = len(a)
    for i in nb.prange(N):
        b[i] = a[i]

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def copyto_numba_combined(a, b):
    if a.shape[0]>4*10**4:
        copyto_numba_p(a, b)
    else:
        copyto_numba_s(a, b)

from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder, MultiArgument

b = BenchmarkBuilder()

b.add_functions([copyto, copyto_numpy, copyto_numba_combined,copyto_numba_s,copyto_numba_p])

@b.add_arguments('array size')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(4, 23):
        size = 2**exp
        arr = np.random.rand(size)
        arr2 = np.empty(size)
        yield size, MultiArgument([arr, arr2])

r = b.run()
r.plot()
```

**Windows, Dektop**

Here it looks like that numpy isn't switching to parallel copying at a certain threshold (this may be also a matter of configuration). With Numba I implemented the switching manually.

[image: Windows]

**Linux, Workstation**

[image: Linux]

**Update: parallel cython version**

```
%%cython -c=-march=native -c=-O3 -c=-ftree-vectorize -c=-flto -c=-fuse-linker-plugin -c=-fopenmp

cimport cython
from cython.parallel import prange
@cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking
@cython.wraparound(False)   # Deactivate negative indexing.
cpdef copyto_p(double[::1] in_array, double[::1] out_array):
    cdef Py_ssize_t idx
    cdef Py_ssize_t size=len(in_array)
    for idx in prange(size,nogil=True):
        out_array[idx] = in_array[idx]
```

[image: Linux]

Comment: These are very interesting results. I didn't expect parallel-processing to give speedups because it's just copying memory around. How many cores do you have?

Comment: 6 on Windows (dual channel memory), 2*6 on Linux (quad channel memory). Do you get the same behavior?

Comment: Instead of zooming into the plots, you can also change the figure size. Often looks a bit better. e.g. `plt.figure(figsize=[10, 8])` before plotting it.

Comment: Cython is on-par with Numba if I use ``%%cython -c=-march=native -c=-O3 -c=-ftree-vectorize -c=-flto -c=-fuse-linker-plugin
cimport cython``. I can guarantee that Numpy, on my system, is only using one core for this. It is probable that @MSeifert is correct and that the speed-up you get might actually not be related to using multiple cores. ``parallel=True`` currently does much more than multithreading! It also has a dedicated optimisation pass and a ``prange`` is a programmer's guarantee that there is no aliasing in the loop. Anyways, that's interesting!

Comment: @user11488411 Can you add a performance plot? Actually the Linux figure above is compiled with the suggested Cython optimization. So above array sizes of 10^4 numba is equivivalent with cython (both single threaded). Numpy definitely uses all cores on my linux machine on array sizes >4*10^5, but not on smaller array sizes.